# How to remove array item from ko.computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have a ko.computed that takes checked off items and adds the object to an array and now I need to be able to remove items from the ko.computed that exists in another array.

So I have a modal dialog with a list of restaurants, when you select the checkbox for a restaurant, it is added to the self.selectedRestaurants and it's id added to self.selectedRestaurantIDs.

The selectedRestaurants is bound to a table that generates a row for each restaurant that was checked off. The selectedRestaurants table has a checkbox as well, so that you can select the items you want to remove.

The issue is I can't figure out how to remove items from the selectedRestaurants, which is a ko.computed observable.

Simplified JS

```
self.selectedRestaurantIDs     = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedRecommendationIDs = ko.observableArray();

     self.selectedRestaurants = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.selectedRestaurantIDs(), function(id) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.toJS(self.restaurants), function(item) {

                return item.id == id; //selected id will be a string
            }); 
        });
    }); 

     self.selectedRecommendations = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.selectedRecommendationIDs(), function(id) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.toJS(self.selectedRestaurants), function(item) {               
                return item.id == id; //selected id will be a string                
            }); 
        });
    });
```

HTML with bindings

```
<ul class="browse-restaurant-list" data-bind="foreach: $root.restaurants">
            <li>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, attr: {value: id}, checked: $root.selectedRestaurantIDs"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
                                <p class="restaurant-meta"><span>Type: <strong data-bind="text: foodType"></strong></span><span>Rating: <strong data-bind="text: rating"></strong></span></p>                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <span><strong>Hours</strong></span>

                                <p data-bind="foreach: $data.hoursOfOperation">
                                    <span class="hour-day" data-bind="text: day"></span>
                                    <span data-bind="text: open"></span>
                                    <span class="hour-open" data-bind="text: open_time"></span>
                                    <span class="hour-close" data-bind="text: close_time"></span><br/>
                                </p>                        
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <strong>Address</strong><br/>
                                <p data-bind="html: fullAddress"></p>                               
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <p><strong>Phone</strong><br/><span data-bind="text: phone"></span></p>                                                                                             
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedRestaurants">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, attr: {value: id}, checked: $root.selectedRecommendationIDs"/></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: foodType"></td>                                                
                        <td data-bind="html: fullAddress"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: rating"></td>
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>
```

Finally my removeSelected function

```
self.removeSelected = function(item) {
        // remove all of the selected restaurant recommendations
        self.selectedRestaurants.remove(item);
     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout 3.0 includes the `checkedValue` binding that will make this a lot simpler and easier, because you'll be able to directly have an observable array of the model objects.

Your binding will become

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedRestaurants"/>
```

And your model will be

```
self.selectedRestaurants = ko.observableArray();
```

You won't need the computed observable.

If you can't use Knockout 3.0 or you want to keep the ID arrays, you should just change your `removeSelected` function to remove the ID value from the ID array:

```
self.removeSelected = function(item) {
    self.selectedRestaurantIDs.remove(item.id);
};
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thanks man...you are the best. I'm using knockout 3 and didn't know about the checkedValue binding. Thanks you saved me a couple of hours at least.